# Survey123 feature reports - summarize number of times an option is chosen in select_multiple questions

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123

I am producing a feature report and would like to summarize the individual entries in a select_multiple question.

Users have the options to select any combination of A, B, C, D. I would like to be able to count across all records how many times each individual answer (A, B, C, or D) appears. T[he documentation](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/browser/analyze-results/featurereportqueries.htm) only notes legal WHERE clause, so that if I broke them each out (e.g. where: "field = 'A'") it would only count options where 'A' was the only option chosen (ignoring A,B or A,C,D etc).

Is there a technique to count every time 'A' is chosen? E.g. in stead of WHERE field = 'A', an equivalent of field LIKE '%A%'?

This is possible using feature sets in dashboards to break them out and summarize them individually but it would be really helpful to count them up in a report.

Comment: In the survey itself there is a 'selected()' function... It's not a great workaround but maybe you could add a new calculated field to the survey itself, something like if(selected(${q1}, 'A'),1,0)+if(selected(${q2}, 'A'),1,0)+...

Comment: I think that would be the next step if I can't find a solution within the reporting structure....it seems like the kind of thing that should exist so I'll hold out hope a little longer. I'd rather not alter the table but if that's what I have to do that's what I have to do.